# hiding some items in dropdownlist in asp.net in c#

Tags: asp.net, drop-down-menu

i have a dropdownlist in which i have two items i need to hide some items for certain users.
I am aware of hiding fields in gridview but not familiar to in hiding dropdown list items.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding ListItems dynamically then in your code do this

```
if (condition){    
    aListItemCollection.Add(new ListItem(aDropDownValue.ToString(), aval));
}
else if(condition){
    aListItemCollection.Add(new ListItem(bDropDownValue.ToString(), bval));
}
```

The same can be achieved using javascript or jquery or directly in html. please let me know how you would like to play with this.

Comment: hi hima  i just added items to dropdownlist using edit items and in that i need to hide the list items for certain users.

Comment: Hi you can do something like this                                    **<%if (user == "xxx")                                                  { %> add the item you want this user <%}%> **

Comment: is the gridview holding your dropdownlist?